# Paypal Recurring Payment - Express Checkout APPID rejected

Tags: c#, paypal

I am using Paypal Express Checkout to make recurring payment and deduct intial amount.

Here are my steps:

I redirect the user to paypal with agreement and get the token

Use this token to deduct initial amount
and then use the same token to create a recurring profile.

This worked well in the sandbox.

Now i need to get an app_id to make it live.

The problem is the paypal reject this saying:

"but i am still seeing the payment as a 'Standard' checkout, rather than a Preapproved Payment.  Preapprovals would be used to create a Billing Agreement with your users which can be debited later "

Can you please advice something?

FINDINGS:

While getting token there is no way to show that we are creating recurring profile that might be the reason they rejected it.
But i am using the same code they provide

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express Checkout and Recurring Payments does not require an App ID.  Those are only required when you're using the Adaptive Payments API.  Express Checkout is not part of the Adaptive Payments API.  That's what they're telling you...you simply don't need an App ID.  If you're passing one in the sandbox it must be getting ignored.

If you have everything working as you want it in the sandbox just change your endpoints and your API credentials to the live values and it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the valueable suggestion. Actually the code i had downloaded from the paypal have this line. Thats why i asked, can you see why it is there in the code - <account apiUsername="uid" apiPassword="*****" apiSignature="AifsBwmajN7BG66iFvPCKIPMZ.UGA8-s3RrRvNCSDW8oGWDQk2kSyAcx" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T" certificateSubject="" signatureSubject="" />